# Dynamically Highlight Active Hypertarget

Tags: highlighting, hypertarget

Is it possible to [dynamically] highlight the active `hypertarget` in a pdf document?

I am using LaTeX (with the `bookmark` package) to create a pdf document (via dvips and ps2pdf) with many pages of problems followed by a few pages of answers.  The user can toggle between a problem and its answer, by clicking the problem number. However, it would be very convenient for the user to have the current target highlighted.  E.g., if the user clicked to see the answer for problem 3, that answer is highlighted in the list of answers.  (Else, the user may have forgotten from where he came to the answers page.)

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\section{Problems}
\begin{description}
\hypertarget{p1}{}\item\hyperlink{a1}{\hspace{-2mm}\bf 1} What is $5\cdot 1$?
\hypertarget{p2}{}\item\hyperlink{a2}{\hspace{-2mm}\bf 2} What is $5\cdot 2$?
\hypertarget{p3}{}\item\hyperlink{a3}{\hspace{-2mm}\bf 3} What is $5\cdot 3$?
\hypertarget{p4}{}\item\hyperlink{a4}{\hspace{-2mm}\bf 4} What is $1\cdot 5$?
\hypertarget{p5}{}\item\hyperlink{a5}{\hspace{-2mm}\bf 5} What is $2\cdot 5$?
\hypertarget{p6}{}\item\hyperlink{a6}{\hspace{-2mm}\bf 6} What is $3\cdot 5$?
\end{description}
\newpage
\section{Answers}
\hypertarget{a1}{}\hyperlink{p1}{\bf 1}~5\ \
\hypertarget{a2}{}\hyperlink{p2}{\bf 2}~10\ \
\hypertarget{a3}{}\hyperlink{p3}{\bf 3}~15\ \
\hypertarget{a4}{}\hyperlink{p4}{\bf 4}~5\ \
\hypertarget{a5}{}\hyperlink{p5}{\bf 5}~10\ \
\hypertarget{a6}{}\hyperlink{p6}{\bf 6}~15\ \
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. Could you please add some text that explains what you want to achieve? And most importantly, extend your code to become a compilable example we can work with.

Comment: @AlexG: Thank you.  According to the edit history, another user "improved formatting" by removing the surrounding text.  Restoring the original version.  Do you still need a compilable code?

Comment: Yes, please. It is common practise here to always provide compilable code, not just fragments in questions.Because completing the code in order to work with it is an additional work for potential helpers. It is something the asker should have done already.

Comment: @AlexG: have replaced the code fragments with a compilable example.